# Pytorch DataParallel crashes runtime

Tags: pytorch, gpu

Whenever I use DataParallel to use multiple GPUs, the whole process crashes.
According to `nvidia-smi`, the use of all GPUs rises to 100% after a few seconds of training. Also, `torchsummary` shows the whole model twice, i.e. all layers appear a second time (what makes the model contain 82.000.000 instead of 41.000.000 trainable parameters), no matter if I use 2 or more GPUs.

I use `DataParallel` as proposed in https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/data_parallel_tutorial.html:

```
Inceptionv4_ = Inceptionv4()
if tc.cuda.device_count() > 1:
    print(tc.cuda.device_count())
    Inceptionv4_ = nn.DataParallel(Inceptionv4_)

Inceptionv4_.to(device)
optimizer = tc.optim.SGD(Inceptionv4_.parameters(), lr=0.005)
print(summary(Inceptionv4_, (3, 224, 224)))
```

Comment: the crashes appeared without any errors? Did it sometimes reboot the OS as well?
Did you find any solution?